# Why is ExecShell ignoring my show type arguments?

Tags: shell, batch-file, window, nsis, silent

I'm trying to execute a batch file silently and asynchronously from an NSIS installer. I want it to be silent to prevent the user from closing it and I want it to be asynchronous so that the installer will close automatically while the batch file is still running. The idea is for the batch file to delete the installer as a way of implementing a self-deleting installer. But this question is about the execution of the batch file specifically.

I can execute a batch file silently using `nsExec::Exec`, and I can execute a batch file asynchronously using `Exec`. I am trying to do both by using `ExecShell` but it's not working. The show type argument seems to be ignored no matter what I pass to it. To confirm that this isn't limited to batch files and `SW_HIDE`, I've tried to open a simple text file minimized and I still can't do it.

```
ExecShell "" "path.txt" SW_SHOWMINIMIZED

ExecShell "open" "path.txt" SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
```

Both of these options simply open WordPad (my default) in a normal non-minimized window. I've tried requesting admin permissions and hiding install details but nothing seems to work. What can I do?

Comment: Mixing .txt and WordPad into this is unfortunate because it depends on the shell registration and WordPad also is free to ignore your request. Please post a simple batch file example (`ping localhost` or whatever) and how you are executing that instead. Please also tell us your Windows version.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. And I thought text files and WordPad were fairly standard so I had no idea they would be able to corrupt this functionality. Could shell registration play into batch files as well? Would this really depend on the contents of the batch file?

Comment: The shell registration can mess up batch files as well if you just assume the default is running the batch file instead of editing it etc. The contents of the batch file do not matter much but it is handy to have if other people need to try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `ExecShell` is `verb command_line [parameters [showmode]]` and you cannot leave out the parameters parameter even if you don't want it, if you do `ExecShell "" "path.txt" SW_SHOWMINIMIZED` then SW_SHOWMINIMIZED is the parameter given to "path.txt". The correct syntax would be `ExecShell "" "path.txt" "" SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`.

You can just do `ExecShell "open" "c:\path\batch.bat" "" SW_HIDE` but that could break if somebody has set batch files to open in their text editor by default. It is better to force the interpreter:

```
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\batch.bat" w
FileWrite $0 "ping localhost$\r$\necho."
FileWriteByte $0 7 ; ASCII Bell so we know it is running even if hidden
FileWrite $0 "$\r$\n"
FileWrite $0 "ping localhost$\r$\n" ; Another ping so ASCII Bell actually makes a sound before the process quits
FileClose $0

ExpandEnvStrings $0 %COMSPEC%
StrCmp $0 "%COMSPEC%" 0 +2
StrCpy $0 "$SysDir\cmd.exe"
ExecShell "" '$0' '/C "$PluginsDir\batch.bat"' SW_HIDE
Abort "Done"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be clear, the important part of your code is passing cmd.exe as the command to ExecShell and the the batch file as the parameter, right? Is it really necessary to see if %COMSPEC% is equal to %COMSPEC% though?

Comment: It's a shame the NSIS manual gets the ExecShell syntax wrong.

Comment: You can use `"$SysDir\cmd.exe"` directly if you don't care about comspec (win95/98/me). The docs are not wrong as far as I can tell but they could perhaps be clearer.

Comment: The documentation puts the parameters and the showmode on the same level, making them both optional without showmode being dependent on parameters. http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html

Comment: Most of the documentation uses that syntax I'm afraid. I'll see what I can do, or at least add an example.